# How to access the shadow root from a script node in a web component

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a web component like this

```
<template id="component">
    <link href="/static/css/main.cacbacc7.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="react-app"></div>
</template>
<script>
  (function (window, document) {
    const doc = (document._currentScript || document.currentScript).ownerDocument;
    const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
      attachedCallback: {
        value: function () {
          const template = doc.querySelector('template#component').content;
          const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
          shadowRoot.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
        }
      }
    });
    document.registerElement('react-webcomponent', { prototype: proto });
  })(window, document);
</script>
```

Inside my `bundle.js` I would like to access my web component, but how do I access it?

I tried using `document.currentScript`, but it always returns `null`, which seems to be [on purpose](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/477), but how would I access the `shadow root` of this component, or to be more specific, how would I access `#react-app` of this component, keeping in mind this web component may be added to the web page more than once.

Comment: did you try parentElement?

Comment: `parentElement` of *what*? `document.currentScript` is always `null`

Comment: since you cannot do that directly you'd better use a workaround, i.e. calling your script from a the custom element